# How to generate valid XML element name from String value in Java

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to generate a valid XML tag from a String value.

I provide this example:

```
String id = "hello world";
Expected XML tag: <hello_world>
```

This is an easy example, but this gets complicated when the String contains other characters like:

```
String id = "34/hello<he"
Expected XML tag: <hello_he> or something valid like this
```

The question is, there is some API or Class which make this process? I know this can be resolved using `replaceAll()`, but I want to know if this can be done automatically.

Comment: From the link below we can tell that valid XML follows these rules:

1. Element names must start with a letter or underscore

2. Element names cannot start with the letters xml (or XML, or Xml, etc)

3. Element names can contain letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, and periods

4. Element names cannot contain spaces

It shouldn't be hard to write a method that takes a string and replaces portions that don't conform. It might need to run multiple times (loop) to check a string doesn't reduce to one that conforms.

https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp

Comment: You can try to use Regex. Not sure what you are trying to do. Do you need to replace anything that is not letters? What decide if `/` gets eliminated vs `<` getting replaced by `_` in your example?

Comment: @clinomaniac I'm trying to generate a valid element name with a String value following this rules: [Rules](https://www.opentechguides.com/tutorials/xml/7/xml-names.html)

Comment: It's not just simple regex because you'll need to remove the offending portions after detecting them, then re-validate. JAXB and other frameworks will likely give you an exception if a tag isn't valid but won't help with changing a String to a valid one.

Comment: @Sam yes I know that it is not a big trouble, but I want to know if this problem have been resolved in some API.

Comment: My feeling is that while checking if a tag is valid is a general problem, making a valid tag from an invalid one is a bit too niche. (Raises questions like which rule do you apply first, in the case of a string starting with XML text, how do you handle it, apply an underscore or just remove - etc)

Comment: Yes, to check to see if its valid, there are a few APIs. I'm not aware of any to transform a string to make it valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one possible algorithm.

1. Initialize the result buffer to "_"
2. For every (Java 16-bit) character in the input:

(2a) If the character is a valid name character other than underscore, append it to the buffer

(2b) Otherwise, append _HHHH to the buffer where HHHH is the character code in hexadecimal.

This algorithm generates a unique name for every input string and is reversible so you can reconstruct the input string from the generated name.

Answer (score -2):

Parse the String and replace special characters.

For element data, use character entities.

Comment: Character entities are not allowed in element and attribute names.